# Excel | See if a Number in One Column is in within a Number Range in Another Column

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula that will show if a number in Column B is within any of the ranges of values in Column A. Here's an example:

Column A:
56 - 85
312 - 516
13 - 36

Column B:
15
311
1536

So the output in Column C should be something like this:
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE

The Column C output can really be anything--the true/false was just an example. I've mostly tried variations of vlookup, but nothing has quite worked. Thanks!

Comment: SO would A1 be "56 - 85" and A2 be "312 - 516" (text values), just to be sure

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I can also edit the sheet so '56' would be in A1 and '85' would be in B1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on feedback to previous answer

Column A = Low Value 
Column B = High Value 
Column C = Check Value 
Column D = Result

Ranges are in order, low to high (so 13 - 36 first, then 56 - 85 second then 312 - 516 third)

Formula for Column D

```
=IF(ISERROR(IF(INDIRECT("B" & (IF(ISNA(MATCH(C2,A:A,1 )),0,MATCH(C2,A:A )))) >= C2, "True", "False")), "False", IF(INDIRECT("B" & (IF(ISNA(MATCH(C2,A:A,1 )),0,MATCH(C2,A:A )))) >= C2, "True", "False"))
```

I think that does it, it works in the online version of Excel anyway

Answer (score 0):

Edit (based on feedback)

This works for checking the value in column A with the range in column A ONLY)
See next answer for actual requested answer

=IF(B1 >= VALUE(MID(A1, 1, FIND(" -", A1, 1))), IF(B1 <= VALUE(MID(A1, FIND(" - ", A1) +2, 99)), "True", "False"), "False")

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, if I'm understanding the formula correctly, that only checks if the number in B1 is within the range found in A1, B2 is within the range in A2, etc. I need to check if the number in Column B is within any of the ranges outlined in Column A.

Comment: So would the ranges be able to be put in order, so 13 - 36 first, then 56 - 85 second then 312 - 516 third?

Comment: Yes, that is possible